# How to pass json encoded results from controller to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to pass json encoded array results from codeigniter controller to javascript variables in view

```
$.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" +"",
  data:{
   d_name:d_name,
   d_password:d_password,
   dataType:"json",
  },
  success: function(result) {
    var obj = parseJSON(result);
    var u = obj.d_name; 
    var v = obj.d_password; 
    alert(v);
},
error: function() { 
  alert("error");
}
 });
```

my output from controller is here:

```
string(61) "[{"id":"1","doc_id":"1","d_name":"done","d_password":"done"}]"
```

i want to assign value of `d_name` and `d_password` to javascript variable to verify

Controller code:-

```
$data['result']=$this->Clinic_model->d_login($d_credentials); 
$result = json_encode($data['result']); 
var_dump($result);die;
```

Comment: put `dataType:"json",` outside of `data` and `var obj = parseJSON(result);` is not required.

Comment: now it showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Put `dataType:"json",` outside of `data`.

2.`var obj = parseJSON(result);` is not required.

3.Now you have array object assign the value.

You need to do like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",
    data:{
        d_name:d_name,
        d_password:d_password
    },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(result) {
        var u = result[0].d_name; 
        var v = result[0].d_password; 
        alert(v);
    },
    error: function() { 
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

And use `echo` in your controller code:

```
$data['result']=$this->Clinic_model->d_login($d_credentials); 
echo $result = json_encode($data['result']);die;
```

Comment: @austin  glad to help you... happy coding...:):)

Comment: @austin  kindly ask a new question for that. As answering question under comment is incorrect. Please don't forget to add input data+code-effort+expected outcome+current output in your next question. You will get answer for sure